# CKEditor: can't set full toolbar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I use: rails 3.2, ckeditor_rails, typus.

As I see in chrome console, all is ok:

```
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = "Full"
```

but only few elements are present in toolbar.

What I do wrong?

Comment: Found in typus-3.1.10/app/views/admin/templates/_text_with_ckeditor.html.erb  ckeditor config setup minimal settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typus fixed: https://github.com/solutus/typus/commit/e193bd2c5dd53b8872555d20813dff1f2af66358